# Good open source Reporting tool/framework for WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, open-source, reporting

I am looking out for a good open source Reporting tool/framework for windows based application (WPF).

The database I am using is sql server 2005.

The typical reports format which I am interested is for e.g. Trial balance, balance sheet,  etc (typical banking / finance reporting application).

There should be good support for charting as well.

If anyone has any experience with reporting for WPF application, your inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it need to be open source or could you use RDLC?

Comment: I am looking for open source tool/framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this may form part of the answer, I thought of putting this in the answer section.
I just found this series of article
[WPF multipage reports](https://web.archive.org/web/20121214141444/http://janrep.blog.codeplant.net/post/WPF-Multipage-Reports-Part-I.aspx) **(note: original link dead, replaced with Wayback Machine link)**.

Thought of putting this here as this may benefit some other learner.  This article walks through creating a reporting framework for LOB Apps.

As the saying goes "A Bird in the hand is worth two in the Bush",  I will have a deep look at this until something else comes up with something better :)

Comment: Did you end up implementing this solution?  I'm in a similar boat and looking for a WPF reporting framework.

Comment: The solution at the provided link is not perfect, but its certainly better than most of the other stuff out there. It handles datagrids better than any other WPF-native solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

[PdfReport](http://pdfreport.codeplex.com/) is a code first reporting engine, which is built on top of the iTextSharp and EPPlus libraries. It's compatible with both .NET 3.5+ Web and Windows applications.

Answer (score 1):

As open source, this doesn't exist, at least not yet. 
It probably doesn't exist commerical offering either. The WPF component market is just getting started.

Comment: Yeah... But will wait for some time if anyone happens to come across some products.. It would be great to know about it.
Thanks.